# Window.open resize to available width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullscreen, window.open

I've done a bit of searching but I can't see if this is possible or not. I would like to use the `window.open()` method to open links to the windows available width and height. Something similar to the below code.

```
var h = $(window).height(); 
var w = $(window).width(); 

$('#window-opener').live('click',function (e) {
        window.open(this.href, 'Resource', 'toolbar=no ,location=0, status=no, titlebar=no, menubar=no,
                    width='+w', 
                    height='+h);
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

Is this possible? If not can anybody recommend a way of doing something similar.

Comment: Have you tried it? Move your var declarations into the function and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code is correct, only missing a ' after the width concatenation:

```
width='+w',
```

must be

```
width='+ w +',
```

I've tried this, maybe i don't understand want you really want to do:

```
var h = screen.height;
var w = screen.width;

$('#window-opener').live('click',function (e) {
    window.open(this.href, 'Resource', 'toolbar=no ,location=0, 
    status=no,titlebar=no,menubar=no,width='+w +',height=' +h);
    e.preventDefault();
});​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UC8Ww/

Comment: The assignment of the h and w variables above are mixed up.  It should read var h = screen.height, not var h = screen.width, and the same for the width variable.

Answer (score 2):

because you are builing your string wrong.

```
width='+w',height='+h);
```

Do you see what you missed? Hopefully you see the missing `+`